# What does $H(\mathcal O_K)[2]$ mean?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I'm currently studying some theory related to an imaginary quadratic field $K$. The definition of $H(\mathcal O_K)$ is the ideal class group of $K$. The notation in the title came up in the following question:

With K as above and letting $\mu$ be the number of primes dividing disc$(\mathcal O_K)$, show that $H(\mathcal O_K)[2]\cong (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{\mu-1}$.

(The question then goes on to address when a prime $p$ can be written in the form $p=x^2+ny^2$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very likely the $2$-torsion of the ideal class group.

Comment: I guess this is the subgroup of elements that has order some power of 2 (and in particular not the subgroup of elements that square to 1) right?